# Multi-threading 4 Accelerometers - Data Unstable

Tags: c++, multithreading, accelerometer

I just started learning C++ this year. Currently, I'm using four accelerometers to calculate human body movement for my school project. I tried to use multi-thread but the data outputs are unstable as such when I tried multiple times, some of the data would change. It does give correct output data sometimes. The output is saved to Microsoft Excel while printing on the screen simultaneously. However, When I tried the accelerometer separately, it seems to work just fine. The output would change only when I multi-thread them together. I can't seem to find what cause the output data to change periodically. I appreciate any help I could get. Pardon my grammatical mistakes for it is not my native language. Thank you =D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "erslib.h"

struct SENSOR_DATA {
    int ID_1, ID_2, ID_3,ID_4;
    int y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4;
    int z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4;
    int x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4;
};

void Thread_0(void);
void Thread_1(void);
void Thread_2(void);
void Thread_3(void);

FILE *fp[4];
errno_t err[4];
int key = 0;

int MainLoopFlag = true;
SENSOR_DATA acc;

int main()
{
 DWORD ThreadID_0;
 DWORD ThreadID_1;
 DWORD ThreadID_2;
 DWORD ThreadID_3;

HANDLE Handle_0 = NULL;
HANDLE Handle_1 = NULL; 
HANDLE Handle_2 = NULL; 
HANDLE Handle_3 = NULL; 

Handle_0 = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread_0, 0, 0, &ThreadID_0);
Sleep(1000);
Handle_1 = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread_1, 0, 0, &ThreadID_1);
Sleep(1000);
Handle_2 = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread_2, 0, 0, &ThreadID_2);
Sleep(1000);
Handle_3 = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Thread_3, 0, 0, &ThreadID_3);
Sleep(1000);

WaitForSingleObject(Thread_0, INFINITE);
WaitForSingleObject(Thread_1, INFINITE);
WaitForSingleObject(Thread_2, INFINITE);
WaitForSingleObject(Thread_3, INFINITE);

//////Print and Data Output//////    
while(MainLoopFlag){
    if(_kbhit()){
        key = _getch();  //a key to start data saving//
        if(key == 'a' && Save_flag==0){
            printf("Preparing for saving...\n");
            Sleep(5000);
            printf("Saving start\n");

            char * fname_0 = ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\adam\\ID 1\\test02.csv");
            err[0] = fopen_s(&fp[0], fname_0,"w+");
            if (fp[0]==NULL) {
                printf("%s File cannot be opened。\n",fname_0);
            return -1;
            }
            char * fname_1 = ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\adam\\ID ２\\test02.csv");
            err[1] = fopen_s(&fp[1], fname_1,"w+");
            if (fp[1]==NULL) {
                printf("%s File cannot be opened。\n",fname_1);
                return -1;
            }
            char * fname_2 = ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\adam\\ID ３\\test02.csv");
            err[2] = fopen_s(&fp[2], fname_2,"w+");
            if (fp[2]==NULL) {
                printf("%s File cannot be opened。\n",fname_2);
                return -1;
            }
            char * fname_3 = ("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\adam\\ID ４\\test02.csv");
            err[3] = fopen_s(&fp[3], fname_3,"w+");
            if (fp[3]==NULL) {
                printf("%s File cannot be opened。\n",fname_3);
                return -1;
            }
            Save_flag=1;
            while(MainLoopFlag && Save_flag==1){ 
                printf("ID->%d, x->%d, y->%d, z->%d \n",acc.ID_1,acc.x_1,acc.y_1,acc.z_1);
                fprintf(fp[0],"%d, %d, %d, %d \n",acc.ID_1,acc.x_1,acc.y_1,acc.z_1);

                printf("ID->%d, x->%d, y->%d, z->%d \n",acc.ID_2,acc.x_2,acc.y_2,acc.z_2);
                fprintf(fp[1],"%d, %d, %d, %d \n",acc.ID_2,acc.x_2,acc.y_2,acc.z_2);

                printf("ID->%d, x->%d, y->%d, z->%d \n",acc.ID_3,acc.x_3,acc.y_3,acc.z_3);
                fprintf(fp[2],"%d, %d, %d, %d \n",acc.ID_3,acc.x_3,acc.y_3,acc.z_3);

                printf("ID->%d, x->%d, y->%d, z->%d \n",acc.ID_4,acc.x_4,acc.y_4,acc.z_4);
                fprintf(fp[3],"%d, %d, %d, %d \n",acc.ID_4,acc.x_4,acc.y_4,acc.z_4);


                if(_kbhit()){
                    key = _getch();
                    //s key to stop data saving
                     if(key == 's' && Save_flag==1){
                        printf("End Data saving\n");

                        Save_flag=0;
                        fclose(fp[0]);
                        fclose(fp[1]);
                        fclose(fp[2]);
                        fclose(fp[3]);
                        MainLoopFlag = false;}
                }

            }

        }
    }
}



// Close Handle
CloseHandle(Handle_0);
CloseHandle(Handle_1);
CloseHandle(Handle_2);
CloseHandle(Handle_3);

return 0;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Thread_1(void)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Thread_1(void)
{
unsigned char buf[4096];
unsigned char buf_data[4096];
unsigned char bin_data[5];
//unsigned char buf_str[4096];
int i,j,n;
int n_cou;
int ComPort = 20;
int flag=0;
int temp_char_1[7];


ERS_Open(ComPort,4096,4096);
ERS_Config(ComPort,ERS_38400|ERS_NO|ERS_1|ERS_8);

//最初に取得するデータは異常なので捨てる
n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);


// 1となる位置を調べる
flag=0;

while(MainLoopFlag){
    n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
    ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if((buf[i] & 0x80) == 0x80){
            flag=1; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)break;
    Sleep(1);
}

// 1 となる位置から後ろをbuf_dataに入れる

n_cou = n - i;
for(j=0;j<n_cou;j++) 
    buf_data[j]=buf[i+j];

while(MainLoopFlag){
    while(MainLoopFlag && n_cou<5){
        n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
        ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)buf_data[n_cou+i]=buf[i];
        n_cou=n_cou+n;
    }


    for(i=0;i<5;i++)bin_data[i]=buf_data[i];

    temp_char_1[0] = (bin_data[0] & 0x38) >> 3; //ID
    acc.ID_2 = (int)temp_char_1[0];

    temp_char_1[1] = (bin_data[0] & 0x07) << 7; // x = 3bit

    temp_char_1[2] = (bin_data[1] & 0x38) << 4; // y = 3bit

    temp_char_1[3] = (bin_data[1] & 0x07) << 7; // z = 3bit

    temp_char_1[4] = (bin_data[2] & 0x7F) | temp_char_1[1]; 
    acc.x_2 = (int)temp_char_1[4];

    temp_char_1[5] = (bin_data[3] & 0x7F) | temp_char_1[2];
    acc.y_2 = (int)temp_char_1[5];

    temp_char_1[6] = (bin_data[4] & 0x7F) | temp_char_1[3];
    acc.z_2 = (int)temp_char_1[6];

    for(i=5;i<n_cou;i++)buf_data[i-5]=buf_data[i];  
    n_cou=n_cou-5;
}

    ERS_CloseAll();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Thread_2(void)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Thread_2(void)
{
unsigned char buf[4096];
unsigned char buf_data[4096];
unsigned char bin_data[5];
//unsigned char buf_str[4096];
int i,j,n;
int n_cou;
int ComPort = 15;
int flag=0;
int temp_char_2[7];


ERS_Open(ComPort,4096,4096);
ERS_Config(ComPort,ERS_38400|ERS_NO|ERS_1|ERS_8);

//最初に取得するデータは異常なので捨てる
n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);


// 1となる位置を調べる
flag=0;

while(MainLoopFlag){
    n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
    ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if((buf[i] & 0x80) == 0x80){
            flag=1; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)break;
    Sleep(1);
}

// 1 となる位置から後ろをbuf_dataに入れる

n_cou = n - i;
for(j=0;j<n_cou;j++) 
    buf_data[j]=buf[i+j];

while(MainLoopFlag){
    while(MainLoopFlag && n_cou<5){
        n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
        ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)buf_data[n_cou+i]=buf[i];
        n_cou=n_cou+n;
    }


    for(i=0;i<5;i++)bin_data[i]=buf_data[i];
    temp_char_2[0] = (bin_data[0] & 0x38) >> 3; //ID
    acc.ID_3 = (int)temp_char_2[0];

    temp_char_2[1] = (bin_data[0] & 0x07) << 7; // x = 3bit

    temp_char_2[2] = (bin_data[1] & 0x38) << 4; // y = 3bit

    temp_char_2[3] = (bin_data[1] & 0x07) << 7; // z = 3bit

    temp_char_2[4] = (bin_data[2] & 0x7F) | temp_char_2[1]; 
    acc.x_3 = (int)temp_char_2[4];

    temp_char_2[5] = (bin_data[3] & 0x7F) | temp_char_2[2];
    acc.y_3 = (int)temp_char_2[5];

    temp_char_2[6] = (bin_data[4] & 0x7F) | temp_char_2[3];
    acc.z_3 = (int)temp_char_2[6];

    for(i=5;i<n_cou;i++)buf_data[i-5]=buf_data[i];  
    n_cou=n_cou-5;
}

    ERS_CloseAll();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Name: Thread_3(void)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Thread_3(void)
{
unsigned char buf[4096];
unsigned char buf_data[4096];
unsigned char bin_data[5];
//unsigned char buf_str[4096];
int i,j,n;
int n_cou;
int ComPort = 3;
int flag=0;
int temp_char_3[7];


ERS_Open(ComPort,4096,4096);
ERS_Config(ComPort,ERS_38400|ERS_NO|ERS_1|ERS_8);

//最初に取得するデータは異常なので捨てる
n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);


// 1となる位置を調べる
flag=0;

while(MainLoopFlag){
    n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
    ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if((buf[i] & 0x80) == 0x80){
            flag=1; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)break;
    Sleep(1);
}

// 1 となる位置から後ろをbuf_dataに入れる

n_cou = n - i;
for(j=0;j<n_cou;j++) 
    buf_data[j]=buf[i+j];

//for(i=0;i<n_cou;i++)printf("%x ",buf_data[i]);
//printf("\n");

while(MainLoopFlag){
    while(MainLoopFlag && n_cou<5){
        n=ERS_CheckRecv(ComPort);
        ERS_Recv(ComPort,buf,n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)buf_data[n_cou+i]=buf[i];
        n_cou=n_cou+n;
    }


    for(i=0;i<5;i++)bin_data[i]=buf_data[i];
    //for(i=0;i<5;i++)printf("%x ",bin_data[i]);
    //printf("\n");

    temp_char_3[0] = (bin_data[0] & 0x38) >> 3; //ID
    acc.ID_4 = (int)temp_char_3[0];

    temp_char_3[1] = (bin_data[0] & 0x07) << 7; // x = 3bit

    temp_char_3[2] = (bin_data[1] & 0x38) << 4; // y = 3bit

    temp_char_3[3] = (bin_data[1] & 0x07) << 7; // z = 3bit

    temp_char_3[4] = (bin_data[2] & 0x7F) | temp_char_3[1]; 
    acc.x_4 = (int)temp_char_3[4];

    temp_char_3[5] = (bin_data[3] & 0x7F) | temp_char_3[2];
    acc.y_4 = (int)temp_char_3[5];

    temp_char_3[6] = (bin_data[4] & 0x7F) | temp_char_3[3];
    acc.z_4 = (int)temp_char_3[6];

    for(i=5;i<n_cou;i++)buf_data[i-5]=buf_data[i];  
    n_cou=n_cou-5;
}

    ERS_CloseAll();
}
```

Correct data :
(Example)

ID->1, x->47, y->147, z->298

ID->2, x->298, y->25, z->147

ID->3, x->47, y->147, z->298

ID->4, x->213, y->123, z->43

ID->1, x->49, y->152, z->222

ID->2, x->256, y->30, z->155

ID->3, x->47, y->147, z->298

ID->4, x->221, y->132, z->54

incorrect data:

ID->1, x->905, y->179, z->20

ID->6, x->47, y->147, z->298

ID->0, x->0, y->0, z->0

ID->4, x->1010, y->56, z->23

ID->1, x->905, y->179, z->20

ID->6, x->47, y->147, z->298

ID->0, x->0, y->0, z->0

ID->4, x->1010, y->56, z->23

Basically the ID shouldn't change while the x, y and z would as you move the accelerometer.

Comment: You haven't included any of your threaded code, how can anyone tell what is wrong without seeing that?

Comment: Besides the code of the threads, you should also clarify what you mean by the data changed. Can you give an example of correct vs incorrect data?

Comment: Looks like you are using some sort of third party library (ERS_Recv etc). Do you know if this library is safe to call from threaded code?

Comment: I'm not seeing any thread synchronization. Your threads are writing to the global variable `acc` and your main function is reading from it. That is never going to work. Maybe you need to read a bit more about how to make multithreading work.

Comment: ERS is `Easy RS-232C`, this library is not thread safe. Check this out for multi-threaded library for RS 232 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Comment: @o_weisman I added some examples.

Comment: @john I'll read up about thread synchronization. Thank you

Comment: Honestly, you're just learning c++, it's much better to stay far, far away from multi threading. Instead read up on arrays and how you could get rid of all this code duplication and var1-var4 declarations. Your computer is more than powerful enough to handle the data from four accelerometers in a single thread.